# Is it possible to save activity state when calling finish() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onsaveinstancestate

I use `startActivityForResult` to switch from my first activity to second activity.
In second activity there's number of checkboxes for user to choose. I get the result from second activity and call `finish()`.

But if the user changes his mind and opens second activity again, it will be recreated and checkboxes will be unchecked.

How can I avoid that? Is it possible to save the state of checkboxes when calling `finish()`?

Answer (score 0):

You call `finish()` which lets the system kill the activity. No, you can't save the  state this way.

I suggest using the shared preferences api to keep any basic information in key value pair format.

But you should read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Or and this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: I'm familiar with Sharedpreference , I guess it is not what i'm looking for. I need a way to save more complex data, like arraylists and custom objects

Comment: Check singleton pattern. You can save more complex stuff there. You can find many tutorials and examples.

Comment: @mrezash  you could also use a parser like GSON and save them as json on Sharedpreference and when you need it back parse it to your custom object or list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for save checkboxes state it using SharedPreferences. Add this code in onStop() in second activity method for saving checkbox state:

```
SharedPreferences options = getSharedPreferences("options", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checkboxState", checkbox.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

And this code inside onStart() method for loading checkbox state:

```
SharedPreferences options = getSharedPreferences("options", 0);
boolean checkboxState = options.getBoolean("checkboxState", false);
checkbox.setChecked(checkboxState);
```